# Accepting output of the socket generated by Python in MQL5

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, zeromq, mql5

I have created a socket file something like the following and want that the output of the socket must be read by the MQL5. See the following Python code:

**daemon.py**

```
import socket
#import arcpy

def actual_work():
    #val = arcpy.GetCellValue_management("D:\dem-merged\lidar_wsg84", "-95.090174910630012 29.973962146120652", "")
    #return str(val)
    return 'dummy_reply'


def main():
    sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
    try:
        sock.bind( ('127.0.0.1', 6666) )

        while True:
            data, addr = sock.recvfrom( 4096 )
            reply = actual_work()
            sock.sendto(reply, addr)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket
import sys


def main():
    sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
    sock.settimeout(1)
    try:
        sock.sendto('', ('127.0.0.1', 6666))
        reply, _ = sock.recvfrom(4096)
        print reply
    except socket.timeout:
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:
        sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Kindly, help me in accepting the output of the socket through MQL5

**EDITED**

I just want that the `reply` should be accepted on the MQL5 in a variable, which produced by the `daemon.py`. How I can do that? Say I want that MQL5 should print the response from the Python , as in the above example, I want that MQL5 should give output as `dummy_reply` in string variable if possible.

Is there any possibility with ZeroMQ?

I want to get the `client.py` to be done with  MQL5 instead of using Python. Please help me.

Comment: You have basic UDP client/server example code there. How does this relate to MQL5? What exactly do you want to communicate with MQL5?

Comment: @AKX I just want that the `reply` should be accepted on the MQL5 in a variable, whch produced by the `daemon.py`. How I can do that? Say I want that MQL5 should print the response from the python , as in the above example, I want that MQL5 should give output as `dummy_reply` in string variable if possible.

Comment: You got what I want to achieve or you have any questions. Feel free to ask please.

Comment: Can anyone hep me with this please let me know?

Comment: What a pity!.. does no one has any answers to my question. I=I guess my bounty is getting wasted everytime I apply for.

Comment: the client.py and zeromq are confusing to me.  are you doing research on socket  in MQL5?  writing another MQL5 program to read from daemon.py?

Comment: @bigdataolddriver Yes, you got it right.

Comment: there are official docs and demos out there  
https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/network
https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/network/socketconnect
you may start from there , and you original question could be much simplified

Comment: I tried working with it. It was a bit confusing stuff. I started my own and created my own ways now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Please find a running example. Important element is to create **byte object** of the payload instead of string before you send as reply. socket object produces and ingests only **bytes**

```python
    import socket
    import threading
    import sys


    def actual_work(data):
       print(data)
       return b'ACK'

    def daemon():
       sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
       sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
       sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 6666))
       print("Listening on udp %s:%i" % ('127.0.0.1', 6666))
       try:

          while True:
              data, addr = sock.recvfrom(4096)
              ack = actual_work(data)
              sock.sendto(ack, addr)
       except Exception as e:
          print(e)  
       finally:
          sock.close()


    def client():
       sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
       sock.settimeout(1)
       try:
           sock.sendto(b'payload', ('127.0.0.1', 6666))
           reply, _ = sock.recvfrom(4096)
           print(reply)
       except socket.timeout as e:
           print(e)
           sys.exit(1)
       finally:
           sock.close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        thread = threading.Thread(target=daemon)
        thread.start()
        client()
        client()
        client()
        client()
        #Issue kill thread here
        thread.join()
```